# How to change data in view depending condition

Tags: php, yii2

I get data in model from some API, in Controller I use it's methods, take data and put it into view. In controller I get all array I need, in view I get different values. But now I trying to make view changeable, its depends from some condition. I have two links in my page, and want when clicked first- show one data,when another-show another. But I won't to create action which will create new view and put in it same data like actionIndex, but have different view in it. How I can avoid that? How I can have different data in one view?

Controller:

```
class RatesController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new ExchangeRates();
        $privatData = $model->getPrivatRate();
        $nbuData = $model->getNationalRate();
        $mejData = $model->getMejBankRate();
        $blackMarketData = $model->getBlackMarketRate();
        $avgUSA = ($privatData[2]["buy"] + $nbuData[0]["rate"] + $mejData[0]["Buy"] + $blackMarketData[0]["Buy"] +
        $privatData[2]["sale"] + $nbuData[0]["rate"] + $mejData[0]["Sale"] + $blackMarketData[0]["Sale"])/8;

        return $this->render('index',['privatdata' => $privatData, 'nbudata' => $nbuData,'mejdata'=>$mejData,'blackdata' => $blackMarketData, 'avgUSA'=>$avgUSA]);
    }
```

View:

```
<div>

    <h2> Курс валют на сегодня</h2>
    <div class="banks">
        <h3>Банки:</h3>
        <h4>ПриватБанк</h4>
        <h4>НБУ</h4>
        <h4>МежБанк</h4>
        <h4>Черный рынок</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="buy">
        <h3> Покупка </h3>
        <p><?php print_r($privatdata[2]["buy"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($nbudata[0]["rate"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($mejdata[0]["Buy"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($blackdata[0]["Buy"])?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="sale">
        <h3> Продажа </h3>
        <p><?php print_r($privatdata[2]["sale"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($nbudata[0]["rate"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($mejdata[0]["Sale"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($blackdata[0]["Sale"])?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="avg_rate">
        <h3>Средний курс на сегодня:</h3>
        <?php print_r($avgUSA)?>

    </div>
</div>
<?= Html::a('USA', ['index.php/rates']) ?>
<?= Html::a('Euro', ['/controller/action']) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have your links add another variable like this:

```
<?= Html::a('USA', ['index.php/rates', 'type' => 'USA']) ?>
<?= Html::a('USA', ['index.php/rates', 'type' => 'EURO']) ?>
```

And in your action this:

```
public function actionIndex($type) {
    if($type == 'USA') {
        // Do something for USA
    }
    elseif($type == 'EURO') {
        // Do something else for EURO
    }
    // Call your view only once, maybe send $type as a parametter so you can make changes to some text displayed
}
```